# Please help me to prove the following Inequality...

Tags: inequality

Is the following inequality true?

Suppose $X_k< \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Then, for $\beta>0$,

$$\frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^{\beta}}{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^{\beta}\right)^n} \le \left[\frac{X_k}{\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}\right]^{\beta}.$$

This inequality is required for one of the problems in my research.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: try with AM-GM inequality

Comment: Yes...Thanks,,,Got it....